# How Can I Reduce Codes In React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**What I'm Trying To Do**

My current code is like this.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Container, Header, Body, View, Content, Title, Text, Left, Right
} from 'native-base';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Fire from 'app/src/Fire';
import {
  StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

export default class All extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const querySnapshot = await Fire.shared.getItems(1);
    const items = await Fire.shared.pushItems(querySnapshot);
    this.setState({ items });
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
        <View>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <Image
              source={{ uri: item.first_img_url }}
            />
            <View>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

I have another component that has almost same code as above one.

The differences are class name and

```js
await Fire.shared.getItems(1);
```

or

```js
await Fire.shared.getItems(2);
```

I know I should combine the same code into one component.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advices or tips :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract this code and pass the number 1 or 2 in props.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Container, Header, Body, View, Content, Title, Text, Left, Right
} from 'native-base';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Fire from 'app/src/Fire';
import {
  StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

export default class All extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const querySnapshot = await Fire.shared.getItems(this.props.nbrOfItems);
    const items = await Fire.shared.pushItems(querySnapshot);
    this.setState({ items });
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
        <View>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <Image
              source={{ uri: item.first_img_url }}
            />
            <View>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

You can call this component in any component like this

```
<All nbrOfItems={1} />
```

Or

```
<All nbrOfItems={2} />
```